# How to store data on client side and update highcharts with range selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'd like to show few charts (highcharts) to user and give to user opportunity do select what range of data he want to see.

I'm very new to jQuery, I tried to google my question, but didn't find the answer.

I want to store on client side data like table with 5 columns.
When user change range selector I want to update charts.

Now I've done with static charts. And I send data right to charts:

```
series: [{                                                                                                                               
  name: "DataA",                                                                                                                        
  pointInterval: 10,                                                                                                                     
  data: <%= @track.get_A_chart_data.to_json %>                                                                                        
},                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                      
  name: "DataB",                                                                                                                    
  pointInterval: 10,                                                                                                                     
  data: <%= @track.get_B_chart_data.to_json %>}                                                                                       
]
```

So, my questions is:

1. Where I can store data that now I send right to chart?
2. Which kind of store in jQuery works like array of hashes or like table. I want to store data in something like table with 5 columns and get pairs (like 1 and 2 col, 1 and 3, etc) for charts?
3. How can I change data in chart when I get event when user change selector?

Could you please give me directions to approach these tasks?

Comment: But why you need to keep data on the user site? Why you cannot use database and get correct data?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, because at one time user will see about 40-50% of all data and I think if data will store on client side it will be much more faster in work but slower on first time load. And if I store all that data on client side I don't need to ask server each time when user change range selector

Comment: @SebastianBochan, if you'll say me that jQuery+AJAX is the right way to approach this task - I'll go that way

Comment: Yes excatly, call ajax makes sense. Obciosuly you can expriment with the local storage (in the browser) or similiar something, but honesly Im not sure if it increase your performance. Definately it will be more complicated.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, Thank you. I'll try to do it with ajax call.

Comment: If you just want to store it in memory client side, it's not jQuery, but plain old javascript.  Arrays of hashes, hashes of arrays, arrays of arrays, javascript has all the typical data structures.

Comment: @Mark, yes, store with js, update with jQuery. Could you tell me where and how I can implement it?

Comment: I've found example which do exact same thing like I want - [dynamic master detail demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail)